# Switching objects in an array without making a new array

Tags: javascript

I'm self-studying data structures and am clearly not grasping how referencing works.

I'm trying to reverse an array WITHOUT creating a new array. So I think I need to store one of the values in a local variable (x in this case) but even so, it's not updating.

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(arr){
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(arr.length / 2); i++){
        let x = i;
        arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[x];
    }
    return arr;
}

let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

My expected result should just be any array reversed.

// → [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

But I'm just getting

// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: You are storing the *index* in `x`, not the *value*.

Comment: actually you're getting [1,2,3,2,1]

Comment: If you dont want to use 3rd variable, refer this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-two-numbers-without-using-temporary-variable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few problems.

First of all, you need to store the *value* in `x`, not the *index*. If you are swapping values then one of the two values will be overriden, that's why you need a copy of it.

Second, the line `arr[i] = arr[x]` is incorrect - `arr[x]` with `x = i` is literally just `arr[i] = arr[i]`. Also, as discussed previously, the value will be overwritten, hence you want so save a value and assign *that* to a new location, otherwise you will link to the overwritten value and just duplicate it in both places.

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(arr){
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(arr.length / 2); i++){
        //arr[arr.length - 1 - i] will be overwritten, so saving that value as x
        let x = arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
        //overwrite the the value
        arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = arr[i];
        //swap the old value to a new position
        arr[i] = x;
    }
    return arr;
}

let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should store the value you're going to be replacing in `x` like so:

```
let x = arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
```

...then replace it (ie: do `arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = arr[i]`), and then use `x` (the value you just replaced) to set the value of `arr[i]` to "swap" the two values

See example below:

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(arr){
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(arr.length / 2); i++){
        let x = arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
        arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = x;
    }
    return arr;
}

let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `let`, I'm assuming you are using ES2015 features. You can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to [swap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Swapping_variables) the array items.

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(arr){
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(arr.length / 2); i++){
        [arr[arr.length - 1 - i], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[arr.length - 1 - i]]
    }
    return arr;
}

let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using:

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(arr){
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(arr.length / 2); i++){
        let temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
        arr[arr.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```